# rolling median in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add rolling medians to my data in ggplot2. Calculating the rolling median in the ggplot aes and in the data.frame itself do not produce similar results (see plots).

[image]

I am looking for a solution within ggplot2 that produces the same results as in the data.frame calculation. I know this can be done with `ggseas::stat_rollapplyr`, but would prefer a solution in base ggplot2.

code;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(gridExtra)

# set up dummy data
set.seed(123)
x = data.table(
  date = rep( seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-04-01"), by = "day"), 2),
  y = c(5 + runif(92), 6 + runif(92)),
  label = c(rep("A", 92), rep("B", 92))
)

x[, `:=` (
  roll = rollmedian(y, k = 15, fill = NA, align = "center")
  ), by = label]

# plots
theme_set(theme_bw())
p = ggplot(x) + 
  geom_line(aes(date, y), col = "lightgrey") + 
  facet_wrap(~label)

# within aes
p1 = p + 
  geom_line(aes(date, rollmedian(y, k = 15, fill = NA, align = "center"))) +
  labs(title = "within aes")

# calculated in data.frame
p2 = p + 
  geom_line(aes(date, roll)) +
  labs(title = "within data.frame")

grid.arrange(p1, p2)

sessionInfo()

    R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8      
     [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] zoo_1.7-13         magrittr_1.5       data.table_1.9.7   ggplot2_2.1.0.9000

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     assertthat_0.1   plyr_1.8.4       rsconnect_0.4.3  tools_3.2.3      gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.2       Rcpp_0.12.

7      grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.3   
[13] lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: It seems to me you have two good solutions already.

Comment: The data.frame I am working on is much bigger than the dummy data here, and I have to make many plots from it. My hope is to add %>% rollmedian to the existing aes once I understand what sort of ggplot2 issue I missed.

Comment: With all respect to your intention to do "everything" within `ggplot`, I believe it is better, in general, to pre-calculate values outside `ggplot`, and then feed it with a clean data set.

Comment: The issue is that ggplot isn't meant to be general purpose statistical software, it's a plotting package. You _can_ do basic things with `stat_smooth` and `stat_summary`, but those are quite limited and it is generally advised to pre-calculate anything more complicated. More generally, I'd usually advise against any calculations within `aes`.

Comment: Why don't you write a simple function that will calculate the median first and then plot? It's then relatively easy to call that function on different parts of the data.

Comment: I agree with you all, Axeman and Henrik. To put it in a different way, I am curious what happened with ggplot2 here, and also why ggseas::stat_rollapplyr works. (if I miss a ggplot2 issue here, I might miss it somewhere else too).

Comment: `ggplot` is not respecting the "group by label" when calculating `rollmedian` within `aes`. Try `identical(ggplot_build(p1)$data[[2]]$y, x[ , rollmedian(y, k = 15, fill = NA, align = "center")])`. The values from this "ungrouped" calculation is then split by the grouping variable "label" into your two facets.

Comment: Basically, `rollmedian(y, k = 15, fill = NA, align = "center")` is evaluated right there and then, without taking any later grouping or faceting into account. See what happens if you rearrange the data.

Comment: Thanks! Can I conclude that you can do calculations in aes row-wise only, and that group-wise fails without warning? (and yes, that it is cleaner to do the calculations in a data.frame).

Comment: I would also recommend outside the plotting environment. Something like `x %>% mutate(roll=rollmedian(y, 15, fill=NA, align='center')) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(date,y,))+geom_line(color='lightgrey')+
   geom_line(aes(date, roll))`

Comment: @ B Williams - it is already in the code (see question), but in data.table. in large data.frames it is much more succinct, faster and no mess of magrittr pipes is required.